# CSS: Scaling problems with different resolutions

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have some major issues with scaling my website on every resolution the same way. I dont even know if its possible to scale it the same way on every display. Its a school project but i cant hand it in when its looking like that. Probably some really stupid beginner problems ...

> that is how it is supposed to look:

[image]

Can you guys give me some tips how to avoid such problems in the future? 
Thanks for any respond.

```js
function muteBtn() {
    var btn = document.getElementById("mute-btn");
    var vid = document.getElementById("video");
    var img = document.getElementById("img");

    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (vid.muted == false) {
            vid.muted = true;
            img.src="bilder/mute.png";
        } else {
            vid.muted = false;
            img.src="bilder/unmute.png"
        }
    });
}
function swapContent() {
    var btn0 = document.getElementById("btn0");
    var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
    var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
    var btn3 = document.getElementById("btn3");
    var btn4 = document.getElementById("btn4");
    var btn5 = document.getElementById("btn5");
    var btn6 = document.getElementById("btn6");
    var home = document.getElementById("p-home");
    var leben = document.getElementById("p-leben");
    var karriere = document.getElementById("p-karriere");
    var alben = document.getElementById("p-alben");
    var filme = document.getElementById("p-filme");
    var ausz = document.getElementById("p-ausz");
    var quellen = document.getElementById("p-quellen");

    var currentid = home;
    home.style.display = "block";

    btn1.addEventListener("click", function () {
        currentid.style.display = "none";
        currentid = leben;
        currentid.style.display = "block";
    });

    btn2.addEventListener("click", function () {
        currentid.style.display = "none";
        currentid = karriere;
        currentid.style.display = "block";
    });
    btn3.addEventListener("click", function () {
        currentid.style.display = "none";
        currentid = alben;
        currentid.style.display = "block";
    });
    btn4.addEventListener("click", function () {
        currentid.style.display = "none";
        currentid = filme;
        currentid.style.display = "block";
    });
    btn5.addEventListener("click", function () {
        currentid.style.display = "none";
        currentid = ausz;
        currentid.style.display = "block";
    });
    btn6.addEventListener("click", function () {
        currentid.style.display = "none";
        currentid = quellen;
        currentid.style.display = "block";
    });
    btn0.addEventListener("click", function () {
        currentid.style.display = "none";
        currentid = home;
        currentid.style.display = "block";
    });
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: black;
    margin: 5px;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: white;
    width: 98%;
    max-height: 32%;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

header h1 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 2px;
    font-size: 5.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.9;
    overflow: hidden;
}

video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    object-position: center;
    object-fit: cover;
}
nav {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 16.44% 0 0 .7%;
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 64.45%;
    padding: 5px;
}
.content-box    {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid white;
    height: 28.6em;
    width: 84.75%;
    overflow: scroll;
    padding: 10px 30px 30px;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 16.6%;
    margin-right: .63%;
    font-family: Arial;
    z-index: -1;
}
.button {
    background-color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.35em;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
    width: 180px;
    text-align: left;
    transition: 200ms;
}
#btn6 {
    top:80%;
}
.button:active {
    transform: translateX(5px);
}
.button:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}
#mute-btn {
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    padding: 4px;
    top: 82%;
    right: .125%;
    transform: scale(0.8);
    z-index: 2;
}
.content-box div p {
    line-height: 125%;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}
.content-box div h1 {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Eminem</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/indexstyles.css">
    <script src="jscript/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            muteBtn();
            swapContent();
        }
    </script>
    <header>
        <h1 id="head">EMINƎM</h1>
            <div class="video">
                <video id="video" autoplay muted loop src="video/rap-god.mp4"></video>
            </div>
        <button type ="button" id="mute-btn"><image id="img" src="bilder/unmute.png"></image></button>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <button type="button" class="button"id="btn0">Home</button>
        <button type="button" class="button"id="btn1">Leben</button>
        <button type="button" class="button"id="btn2">Karriere</button>
        <button type="button" class="button"id="btn3">Alben</button>
        <button type="button" class="button"id="btn4">Filme</button>
        <button type="button" class="button"id="btn5">Auszeichnungen</button>
        <button type="button" class="button" id="btn6">Quellen</button>
    </nav>
    <div class="content-box">
        <div id="p-home">
            <h1>Home: </h1>
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>
        <div id="p-leben" style="display:none">
            <h1>Leben: </h1>
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>
        <div id="p-karriere" style="display:none">
            <h1>Karriere: </h1>
            <p>Content </p>
        </div>
        <div id="p-alben" style="display:none">
            <h1>Alben: </h1>
            <p>3</p>
        </div>
        <div id="p-filme" style="display:none">
            <h1>Filme: </h1>
            <p>4</p>
        </div>
        <div id="p-ausz" style="display:none">
            <h1>Auszeichnungen: </h1>
            <p>5</p>
        </div>
        <div id="p-quellen" style="display:none">
            <h1>Quellen: </h1>
            <p>6</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: look into media queries. You can define styles for particular screen widths/heights

Answer (score 1):

This might be of use to you.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

But the main thing, as other people have already mentioned, is to look into using media queries. Which will let you target blocks of CSS at certain screens sizes.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp